# Rotate table in appendix result in a redundant page between the table and the appendix header

Tags: tables, rotating

I am new user of latex and now writing my thesis with it. I am trying to fit a long table in the appendix. I use `\rotatebox` to make the table fit like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsbsy}
\usepackage{dcolumn,array}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage[noprefix]{nomencl}


\begin{document}   
\chapter{appendix}

\begin{table}[tp] 

\rotatebox{90}{

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}

\hline

   & 0.01      & 0.02      & 0.03      & 0.04      & 0.05      & 0.06       \\ \hline

1  & 0.00E+00  & 0.00E+00  & 0.00E+00  & 0.00E+00  & 0.00E+00  & 0.00E+00   \\ \hline

2  & 0.00E+00  & 0.00E+00  & 0.00E+00  & 0.00E+00  & 0.00E+00  & 0.00E+00   \\ \hline

3  & 0.00E+00  & 0.00E+00  & 0.00E+00  & 0.00E+00  & 0.00E+00  & 0.00E+00   \\ \hline

\end{tabular}

}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

However, it always gives me a blank page with only the header of the appendix and put the table in a new page, like this:
[image]
[image]

Hope someone can help. Thanks a lot :).

Comment: Don't put it in a `table`.

Comment: The table is too big. you will have to reformat it. Please show a full MWE which leaves us without guessing around. Thanks.

Comment: It is not because of the table size.